# Где надо изменить код чтоб исчезли эти ошибки

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-code

Ошибки:

1. 'Doors.collider' hides inherited member 'Component.collider'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. (Doors название класса)
2. An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Component.transform'

Я сильно еще не разбираюсь в кодинге, и хотел бы узнать мой косяк в данном коде. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class Doors: MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float OPENABLE_DISTANCE = 1.5f;
    private  static bool isOpened;
    private  static SpriteRenderer rend;
    private  static BoxCollider2D collider;

    [SerializeField] private Sprite OpenedDoor, ClosedDoor;

    private void Awake () {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }
    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, PlayerMovement.transform.position);
            if (dist <= OPENABLE_DISTANCE) {
                MoveDoor(!isOpened);
            }
        }
    }
    private void MoveDoor (bool open) {
        if (open) {
            rend.sprite = OpenedDoor;
            collider.enabled = false;    
        }
        else {
            rend.sprite = ClosedDoor;
            collider.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены что Вам нужны статические поля? Возможно Вы не до конца понимаете зачем они Вам тут

Comment: Да вы правы, я еще не сильно разбираюсь в теории static. Но я думаю нынешний отредаченный код (я отправил и отметил как решение) подойдёт с static в SpriteRenderer и в BoxCollider2D. Спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал код. Он сработал. Спасибо кто помог с решением ошибки!

```
public class DoorOpens: MonoBehaviour

{

    private const float openableDistance = 1.5f;

    private  static BoxCollider2D collider;

    private  static SpriteRenderer sr;

    [SerializeField] private Sprite OpenedDoor, ClosedDoor;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerMovement playerMovement;

    private void Awake() {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerMovement.transform.position);
            if (dist <= openableDistance) {
                SetStay();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetStay() {
        if (collider.enabled == true) {
            sr.sprite = OpenedDoor;
            collider.enabled = false;    
        }
        else if (collider.enabled == false) {
            sr.sprite = ClosedDoor;
            collider.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ на 1**

Вы создаёте новое поле `collider` и этим скрываете унаследованный от класса `Component` поле с таким же названием, Вам необходимо переименовать поле под другим названием, к примеру: boxCollider2D и тому подобное по усмотрению, и использовать эту переменную далее.

***Пример:***

```
private BoxCollider2D _boxCollider2D;

private void Start()
{
    _boxCollider2D.enabled = true;
}
```

**Ответ на 2**

Вы хотите получить `transform` у класса без обьявления его на сцене, напрямую через класс, Вам нужно его проинициализировать, и использовать ссылку на обьект, создайте поле для `PlayerMovement`, перетащите в инспекторе обьект с таким компонентом внутри, и используйте это поле, и используйте эту переменную далее

***Пример*:**

```
[SerializeField] private PlayerMovement _playerMovement;

private void Start()
{
    _playerMovement.transform.position = transform.position
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 'Doors.collider' hides inherited member 'Component.collider'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. (Doors название класса)

У вас в классе `Doors` уже есть готовый `collider`, доставшийся ему от класса-предка, не нужно объявлять его заново как статическое поле класса.

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Component.transform'

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно инициализировать `transform` в конструкторе класса, так же как вы это делаете с `collider`, например. Но я не настолько хорошо знаю `Unity`, могу тут и ошибаться. Ошибки должны быть представлены в вопросе в виде стек-трейса, чтобы было понятно, к каким строкам кода они относятся. У вас непонятно.